# java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid descriptor index

Tags: java, jdbc

The following code snippet

```
    String query = " SELECT * FROM accessdb.user;";
    try
    {
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
        rs.first();
        String s = "";
        do
        {

            s = s + rs.getInt(0) + "\t\t" + rs.getString(1) + "\t\t" 
                + rs.getString(2) + "\n";
            rs.next();
        }
        while (!rs.isLast());
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("\nError for firing query");
    }
```

produces the following exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid descriptor index
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

> rs.getInt(0)

JDBC column indexes start from `1`. So you should retrieve data as follows:

```
s = s + rs.getInt(1) + "\t\t" + rs.getString(2) + "\t\t" + rs.getString(3) + "\n";
```

Using the column names in `rs.get*()` is much better and shields your code from any change in the order of the columns returned, in general.

Comment: Thanx Vikdor problem is solved now. Instead of using index i used name of the columns and that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Using the column names in `rs.get*()` is much better and shields your code from any change in the order of the columns returned, in general.

I found column names without double quote will be raise same error.